# SQLAlchemy: How to configure generic associations with abstract parent

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I wanted to create a table with generic associations, so I followed one of the  [available examples on Github](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/tree/master/examples/generic_associations).

The example I choose that may  fit the best on my use of case is called **table per association**, and it says:

> Illustrates a mixin which provides a generic association via a
> individually generated association tables for each parent class. The
> associated objects themselves are persisted in a single table shared
> among all parents. This configuration has the advantage that all
> Address rows are in one table, so that the definition of "Address" can
> be maintained in one place.   The association table contains the
> foreign key to Address so that Address has no dependency on the
> system.

**It works well, but to adapt it to my own use of case, I need to guarantee that every row of the Address table has at least one association. Is that possible, how could I do that?**

The code of the example is shown below:

```py
    @as_declarative()
    class Base(object):
        """Base class which provides automated table name
        and surrogate primary key column.
        """
    
        @declared_attr
        def __tablename__(cls):
            return cls.__name__.lower()
    
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    
    
    class Address(Base):
        """The Address class.
        This represents all address records in a
        single table.
        """
    
        street = Column(String)
        city = Column(String)
        zip = Column(String)
    
        def __repr__(self):
            return "%s(street=%r, city=%r, zip=%r)" % (
                self.__class__.__name__,
                self.street,
                self.city,
                self.zip,
            )
    
    
    class HasAddresses(object):
        """HasAddresses mixin, creates a new address_association
        table for each parent.
        """
    
        @declared_attr
        def addresses(cls):
            address_association = Table(
                "%s_addresses" % cls.__tablename__,
                cls.metadata,
                Column("address_id", ForeignKey("address.id"), primary_key=True),
                Column(
                    "%s_id" % cls.__tablename__,
                    ForeignKey("%s.id" % cls.__tablename__),
                    primary_key=True,
                ),
            )
            return relationship(Address, secondary=address_association)
    
    
    class Customer(HasAddresses, Base):
        name = Column(String)
    
    
    class Supplier(HasAddresses, Base):
        company_name = Column(String)
    
    
    engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    
    session = Session(engine)
    
    session.add_all(
        [
            Customer(
                name="customer 1",
                addresses=[
                    Address(
                        street="123 anywhere street", city="New York", zip="10110"
                    ),
                    Address(
                        street="40 main street", city="San Francisco", zip="95732"
                    ),
                ],
            ),
            Supplier(
                company_name="Ace Hammers",
                addresses=[
                    Address(street="2569 west elm", city="Detroit", zip="56785")
                ],
            ),
        ]
    )
    
    session.commit()
    
    for customer in session.query(Customer):
        for address in customer.addresses:
            print(address)
            # no parent here
```

It then creates three tables on the database:

`Address`, `CustomerAddress` and `SupplierAddress`.

I wanted to assure that an `Address` will always be attached either to a `CustomerAddress` or a `SupplierAddress`.

Like if the `Address` was an **abstract class**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the [**association in discriminator** example](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/examples/generic_associations/discriminator_on_association.py) would fit better to my case.

It's not the most speed or storage wise of them, but it's what I need.

It is  a

> mixin which provides a generic association using a single target table
> and a single association table, referred to by all parent tables.  The
> association table contains a "discriminator" column which determines
> what type of parent object associates to each particular row in the
> association table. SQLAlchemy's single-table-inheritance feature is
> used to target different association types. This configuration
> attempts to simulate a so-called "generic foreign key" as closely as
> possible without actually foregoing the use of real foreign keys.
> Unlike table-per-related and table-per-association, it uses a fixed
> number of tables to serve any number of potential parent objects, but
> is also slightly more complex.

I just modified the `ForeignKey` definition on the `Address` class to forbid the absence of an association.

```
class Address(Base):
    """The Address class.
    This represents all address records in a
    single table.
    """

    association_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("address_association.id"), nullable=False)
```

---

Now, this would be accepted:

```
session.add(
    Supplier(
        company_name="Ace Hammers",
        addresses=[Address(street="2569 west elm", city="Detroit", zip="56785")],
    ),
)
session.commit()
```

While this not (violates not null constraint):

```
session.add(Address(street="2569 west elm", city="Detroit", zip="56785"))
session.commit()
```